# Upgrade React v16 to v16.8

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to upgrade my web application from React v16.0 to v16.8, but I am a beginner and I have never tried it before. Is it safe to perform this upgrade? 
Is there a command which can upgrade all the libraries that I am using?

I am using the following libraries:
react-router-dom, axios, redux, redux-logger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `yarn upgrade` to upgrade all of your dependencies..however, if there are any breaking changes in any of these libraries then you might face problems. So whether  or not it's 'safe' to perform this upgrade depends entirely on your codebase and the set of libraries you are using.

You can also try `yarn upgrade react` to only upgrade react.

**PS:** `npm update` is the npm analogue of this command.